# How does an IP address change affect a classic-asp site on IIS?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

One of our customers is planning to change the public IP address of their server where their website is hosted (in-house on IIS).

The website was built with **Classic ASP**.

What changes are needed on the server after the IP address change, and where would they be?

(I know this question is very vague but this is all the information I have for now  - apologies.)

Answer (score 1):

Normally there will be no dependencies on a specific IP address in classic ASP.

**IIS** ofcourse manages on which IP address(es) and which hostnames the (asp) site will respond (in the bindings setting for the site), and the public **DNS** settings are responsible for routing the proper hostname to the correct (new) IP address, but ASP code doesn't care about hostnames or ip-addresses, it just responds to whatever IIS thinks should be handled by the site in question.

The DNS will propably be hosted at the companies Internet provider, you should check if the site in IIS has the correct bindings, and if it is not configured to respond to specifically the old IP address.

Comment: @ITDe if the answer is correct, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the server uses multiple IP addresses you may need to alter the bindings in IIS manager to ensure that the domain of your website is associated with the correct IP, and obviously you will need to update the DNS record for your domain.  Neither of these are specific to Classic ASP